# Cannot upload more than 4 files to the api server from blazor side

Tags: c#, file-upload, signalr, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I'm trying to add a new function where user can upload images and videos similar to facebook in blazor server .NET 6, I created a new api and followed [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server) of uploading files, Everything is working so far with uploading up to 4 files, but when I'm trying to upload more than 4 it doesn't send a request to the api at all. and after a while it shows these two exceptions[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9pk0.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP0Ja.png)
Here's the code I'm having: `

```
private List<File> files = new();
private List<UploadInfo> uploadResults = new();
private int maxAllowedFiles = 10;
private bool shouldRender;

protected override bool ShouldRender() => shouldRender;

private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    shouldRender = false;
    long maxFileSize = (long)(4 * Math.Pow(10, 8));
    var upload = false;

    using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles(maxAllowedFiles))
    {
        if (uploadResults.SingleOrDefault(
            f => f.FileName == file.Name) is null)
        {
            try
            {
                var fileContent = 
                    new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize));

                fileContent.Headers.ContentType = 
                    new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);

                files.Add(new() { Name = file.Name });

                content.Add(
                    content: fileContent,
                    name: "\"files\"",
                    fileName: file.Name);

                upload = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogInformation(
                    "{FileName} not uploaded (Err: 6): {Message}", 
                    file.Name, ex.Message);

                uploadResults.Add(
                    new()
                    {
                        FileName = file.Name, 
                        ErrorCode = 6, 
                        Uploaded = false
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    if (upload)
    {
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = 
            await client.PostAsync($"https://localhost:7134/api/Files/FileUpload", content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
            };

            using var responseStream =
                await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var newUploadResults = await JsonSerializer
                .DeserializeAsync<IList<MediaAPI.UploadInfo>>(responseStream, options);

            if (newUploadResults is not null)
            {
                uploadResults = uploadResults.Concat(newUploadResults).ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    shouldRender = true;
}`
```

When I try to debug it, the debug point disappears when it sends the request:
`await client.PostAsync($"https://localhost:7134/api/Files/FileUpload", content);`
Anyone has experiansed this issue before?
Thanks in advance.